# difference in incrementing pointer with ** and without in C

Tags: c, pointers, increment

I've got an issue in understanding the difference in  this two ways of incrementing pointers :

```
int **a;

a++;      //works fine
**a++;    //same here
a += n;   //still good
**a += n; //is not the same and I can't figure out what is going on
```

I was trying to print parameters of the program in reverse order here

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    argv += argc;                 //works fine until it is changed to 
                                  //                   **argv += argc
    while (--argc > 0)
    {
        argv--;
        (*argv)--;
        while (*(*argv)++)
            ft_putchar(**argv);
        if (argc - 1 > 0)
            ft_putchar('\n');
    }
    return (1);
}
```

Summing the question - why the second way is not working the same?

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)?

Comment: nope, just an example to be more clear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### What I think is confusing you:

`**a++` is parsed as `**(a++)` while
`**a += n` is parsed as `(**a) += n`

This is due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

My advice is to always use parenthesis in cases like this to avoid any confusion.

Now on to each case:

#### Case 1

```
a++
```

Pointer arithmetic. Post-increments `a`

#### Case 2

```
**a++
```

is parsed as `**(a++)`

- it post increments `a` - Pointer arithmetic
- the result of evaluating `(a++)` is `a` - the value before the increment
- then you have a double indirection.

So the above is equivalent (more or less) with the following:

```
**a;
a = a + 1;
```

#### Case 3

```
a += n
```

Pointer arithmetic. I would expect self-explanatory.

#### Case 4

```
**a += n
```

This is parsed as

```
(**a) += n
```

So you do a double indirection on `a` getting the value of the pointed integer and then you increase that integer (integer arithmetic).